# R - fast way to count data frame lines with two columns set to specific values

Tags: r

I have a data.frame tr_id_cat made of two columns: id, category.

- tr_id_cat has 15 million lines
- id has 300 thousand unique values
- category has 20 unique values

I would like to build a count matrix:

My code so far, but it takes ages:

```
# id and categories are lists of the possible values (dictionary)
nb_id = length(id)
nb_categories = length(categories)
COUNT_ID_CATEGORY = array( 0, dim=c(nb_id,nb_categories) )

for(i in (1:nb_categories))
{
    cat_ = categories[i]
    subs = tr_id_cat[ tr_id_cat$category == cat_ ,]

    for(j in(1:dim(subs)[1]))
    {
        id_  = subs$id[j]
        id_idx  = which(id == id_)
        COUNT_ID_CATEGORY[id_idx,cat_idx] = dim(subs[ subs$id == id_,])[1];
    }
}
```

---

Small version of what I am trying to do:

```
id, category
1, 1
1, 1
1, 1
1, 2
1, 2
2, 1
3, 1
```

would be converted into a count matrix:

```
COUNT_ID_CATEGORY[1,1] = 3 # first three lines
COUNT_ID_CATEGORY[1,2] = 2 # line 4 and 5
COUNT_ID_CATEGORY[2,1] = 1
COUNT_ID_CATEGORY[2,2] = 0
COUNT_ID_CATEGORY[3,1] = 1
COUNT_ID_CATEGORY[3,2] = 0
etc
```

Comment: Did you try dplyr or data.table approaches? Could you provide a minimal example of your dataset and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `data.table` and `reshape2`.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

# Number of rows
n <- 15e6

# Generate test data
tr_id_cat <- data.table(id = ceiling(runif(n) * 300e3),
                        category = ceiling(runif(n) * 20))

# set keys
setkey(tr_id_cat, id, category)

# count
tab <- tr_id_cat[, .N, keyby = list(id, category)]

# reshape as array
dcast.data.table(tab, id ~ category, value.var = "N", fill = 0L)
```

Here I have added the solution by @Arun. And I have added the timing results also. It seems that Arun's solution takes approximately 20% more time.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(rbenchmark)

f1 <- function(n = 15e6) {
  tr_id_cat <- data.table(id = ceiling(runif(n) * 300e3),
                          category = ceiling(runif(n) * 20))
  setkey(tr_id_cat, id, category)
  tab <- tr_id_cat[, .N, keyby = list(id, category)]
  dcast.data.table(tab, id ~ category, value.var = "N", fill = 0L)
}

f2 <- function(n = 15e6) {
  tr_id_cat <- data.table(id = ceiling(runif(n) * 300e3),
                          category = ceiling(runif(n) * 20))
  tab <- tr_id_cat[, .N, by = list(id, category)]
  dcast.data.table(tab, id ~ category, value.var = "N", fill = 0L)
}

benchmark(f1(), f2(),
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"),
          replications = rep(10, 3))
```

Results on my machine:

```
  test replications elapsed relative
1 f1()           10   61.62    1.000
3 f1()           10   62.21    1.010
5 f1()           10   61.60    1.000
2 f2()           10   73.55    1.194
4 f2()           10   74.31    1.206
6 f2()           10   73.33    1.190
```

Comment: This seems perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: `data.table` has it's own `dcast` and probably much faster than `reshape2` one

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg! I thought that I am using the `dcast` from `data.table` but I was not. Because `dcast` from `data.table` is not S3 generic yet. Correction applied.

Comment: @djhurio could your code accommodate a reshape (melting) of the output to approach those from plyr and dplyr?

Comment: @PauloCardoso, I did not get what you are asking for.

Comment: @djhurio Sorry. I'd like to know if the resulting data.table could be a molten version of your dcast, avoiding another line with `melt(dcastdatabale, id = 'id')`.

Comment: @PauloCardoso, `tab` is a molten version of data. I thought @tucson is looking for a casted version of data.

Comment: @djhurio, +1. You don't need `setkey` or `keyby` here.. `dcast.data.table` internally takes care of sorting the result.

Comment: @Arun, I am doing counting with `data.table` and `keyby` not with `dcast`. Not sure which is faster. And `setkey` before `keyby` could improve the performance.

Comment: @Arun, your suggested solution takes 20% more execution time. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to obtain something like this

```
library(dplyr)
tr_id_cat %.% group_by(id,category) %.% summarise(n=n())
```

Comment: It could be the fastest way?

Comment: I can't see how exactly it can work. could you add the data structure? Ok, tr_id_cat is the data.frame.

Answer (score -1):

Something as simple as this?

```
d <- data.frame(category = rep(c(1:3), 3),
                id = rep(c(1:3), 3))
d$tr_id_cat <- with(d, paste0(category, id))

library(plyr)
ddply(d, .(tr_id_cat), summarise, n=length(tr_id_cat))
```

or, taking d without tr_id_cat variable

```
plyr::count(d, .(category, id))
```

or with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
d %.%
  dplyr:::group_by(tr_id_cat) %.% 
  dplyr:::summarise(n = length(tr_id_cat))
```

Comment: I don't believe that he has tr_id_cat as a separate column

Comment: I don't understand this -1. All proposed solutions work just fine, both with or without the extra tr_id_cat column.